# VS2019 debug chromium black screen

Tags: c++, google-chrome, debugging, chromium

This is my compile option：**gn gen --ide=vs --filters=//chrome out\x86_debug --args="is_component_build = true is_debug = true enable_nacl = false target_cpu = "x86""**

Then finished compile, run chromium its black screen.

[image: chromium dialog]

[image]

Can somebody tell me what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this option **--disable-gpu**
its running good